TCL / TK script
I want to run the script .tcl in the terminal.
I downloaded TCL from and I checked it with the line below, at which a window appears as in the photo.
% C:\ActiveTcl\bin\wish

The script starts with tclsh, but immediately gives errors. For example, code below show invalid command name "frame" or invalid command name "button".
frame .f2
text .f1.t1 -width 60 -height 20 
button .f2.b1 -text "Quit" -width 5 -command {exit}
button .f2.b2 -text "Next" -width 5 -command {module_conf}

Why doesn't it work? Do these code lines refer to TK? Did I install TK with TCL? How can I fix this? What else do I need to download?

Those are Tk commands, yes, so use wish to run it instead of tclsh. The former automatically loads the Tk module.

Those are commands typical of Tk. To use them, you either need to launch the file with wish instead of tclsh, or put this at the top of your script:
package require Tk

These options are largely equivalent on Linux, but less so on Windows and macOS, which differentiate more strongly between programs run in terminals and programs that use the GUI; wish handles those details for you.
